# Flutter dependecy conflict

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

> Because flutter_math_fork >=0.4.0 depends on provider ^6.0.0 and google_maps_place_picker >=2.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on provider ^5.0.0, flutter_math_fork >=0.4.0 is incompatible with google_maps_place_picker >=2.0.0-nullsafety.0.
> And because no versions of google_maps_place_picker match >=2.0.0-nullsafety <2.0.0-nullsafety.0, flutter_math_fork >=0.4.0 is incompatible with google_maps_place_picker >=2.0.0-nullsafety.

```
dependencies:
```

## GET

get: ^4.6.1
get_storage: 2.0.3

## DIO

dio: ^4.0.4
dio_http_cache: 0.3.0

## FONT

google_fonts: ^2.1.1
#IMAGES, SLIDERS, LAYOUTS
cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
carousel_slider: 4.0.0
flutter_svg: ^1.0.0
flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.1
image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
cupertino_icons: any
shimmer: 2.0.0

## WEB

webview_flutter: ^2.8.0
flutter_html: ^2.0.0
url_launcher: ^6.0.17

## FIREBASE

firebase_messaging: ^11.2.4
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.5
firebase_auth: ^3.3.4
firebase_core: ^1.10.6
firebase_storage: ^10.2.4

## GOOGLE MAPS

google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.3.2
google_maps_place_picker: ^2.0.0-nullsafety
flutter_downloader: ^1.7.1
path_provider: ^2.0.8
permission_handler: ^6.0.1+1
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter
file_picker: ^4.2.4
intl: ^0.17.0
change_app_package_name: ^1.0.0
flutter_math_fork: ^0.6.0

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_launcher_icons: 0.9.2

I need help

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you `upgrade` your any `dependency` that depends on some other dependency.  You need to `downgrade` dependencies `versions` one by one so that the issue can be solved.

or you can also run `pub outdated` command to get a list of `resolvable version` that can be used for your dependencies.